# C++-conversion function template deduction, why does this work?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

```
class A
{
    struct B{};
public:
    static void test(A::B){}
};

struct C
{
    template<class T>
    operator T()
    {
        return T();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A::test(C());
}
```

This code works for clang 3.7, gcc 5.1 and vc++ 14.2.
2 problems,
1. Why can template deduce the type is A::B? (so smart!)
As far as I know, template deduce the type by return statement instead of parameter.
But I found something interested in N4606 12.3.2 6 `A conversion function template shall not have a deduced return type (7.1.7.4).` (However, I cannot find further information about this, because 7.1.7.4 is too hard to understand.)
2. Why could conversion function template access A::B?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why can template deduce the type is A::B? (so smart!)

Since `test()` takes an `A::B`, you need a way to convert a `C` to an `A::B`. We can attempt an initialization by conversion function, for which we have in [over.match.conv]:

> The conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered. Those non-explicit conversion
>   functions that are not hidden within `S` and yield type `T` or a type that can be converted to type `T` via
>   a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) are candidate functions.

We perform template deduction according to [temp.conv]:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing the return type of the conversion function template (call
>   it P) with the type that is required as the result of the conversion (call it A; see 8.6, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6 for
>   the determination of that type) as described in 14.8.2.5.

Basically, we deduce the `T` in `template <class T> operator T()` to be `A::B`. This is a well-formed conversion sequence, and the only viable one, so that's what happens.

The line you quote, about "deduced return type", refers to `auto` or `decltype` in the return type. This doesn't happen here.

> 2. Why could conversion function template access A::B?

Access rules are strictly about names. The **name** `B`, and only the name, is private to `A`. But we're not accessing the **name**, we're deducing the type directly.

`B`'s constructor is public, so the body of the conversion function is also well-formed, so everything about the code is well-formed.

Comment: Oh, I got it. `deduced return type` is at `7.1.7.4`, but `conversion function template shall not have a deduced return type`. That means `7.1.7.4` has nothing familiar with `conversion function`. I don't need to read `7.1.7.4` part.

Comment: Where can I get further information about the access control with `type` but not `name`?

Comment: @Caesar There is no such thing as access control with type.

Comment: We are using type deduction, at that time, we are not trying to access A::B. Instead, we are just comparing the type. Comparing type doesn't violet the access control. Do you mean this?

Comment: But when the compiler tries to construct `B`, does not the compiler violate the access control?

Comment: @Caesar No, like I said in the answer, access control is about names. We don't have access to the *name* `B`, but we're not accessing it by name.

Comment: Well, I still don't get it. :|

Answer (score 0):

To oversimplify things slightly:

Making an inner class or a function private only means that the name of the class or a function can be used only by the class, and it is inaccessible otherwise. You cannot write any code that uses the name the private class or a function, outside of the class.

In the shown code `A::B` is not used anywhere outside of the class.

This works too, for the same exact reason:

```
class A {

    class B {};

public:

    B foo();
};


int main()
{
    A a;

    auto bar=a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

`auto` works. `A::B` will not work.